# Cambiar el tiempo de Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

Tengo el siguiente código que envía alertas cuando se acaba el tiempo de expiración, el problema es que se envía cada minuto y es muy tedioso ya que el ACTION_TIME_TICK envía la alerta cada minuto, ¿Hay alguna forma de enviar el mismo mensaje pero cada 24 hrs?

```
_broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0) {
                strFecha = _sdfWatchTime.format(new Date());
            }
            try {
                String fechaExpe= "2018-09-01";
                fechaExp = formatoDelTexto.parse(fechaExpe);
                date1    = formatoDelTexto.parse(strFecha);
            }catch (ParseException e) {              // Insert this block.
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int compa = date1.compareTo(fechaExp);
            if(compa>0 || compa==0){
                AlertFechaExpe();
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(_broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
```

Comment: para eso deberias usar el servicio del AlarmManager para hacerlo cada 24 hs

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, tengo que implementarlo junto con el BradcastReceiver o únicamente con AlarmManager?